# New process out of order?

Tags: c#

I wasn't able to find the answer I'm looking for already here, but if it is please link it and I'll close this duplicate post.

As part of a program I'm working on, I want three simple things to happen in this order:

1.) Show a marquee progress bar
2.) Run some commands in through CMD and move the output to an accessible string
3.) Stop/hide the progress bar

The problem I'm seeing is that my code is not executing in order and I'm super confused as to why.  It seems to go step 2-1-3 which shouldn't be possible.

To make things even weirder, if I un-comment a message box between Step 1 and Step 2, things execute in order.

Is there something with the new CMD process throwing this out of wack?

Here's my code for this method:

```
        //STEP 1 - Updates label and starts progress bar
        lblSelectDiagnostic.Text = "Diagnostic Running";
        progressBarDiag.Visible = true;
        progressBarDiag.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 100;

        //MessageBox.Show("Status Updated");

        //STEP 2 - Runs "Test Internet Connection"

        //Gets selected diagnostic name
        string strSelectedDiag = listBoxDiagnostics.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var name = strSelectedDiag.Substring(strSelectedDiag.LastIndexOf(':') + 1);
        strSelectedDiag = name.Trim();

        if (strSelectedDiag.Contains("Test Internet Connection"))
        {
            //Pings Google
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            //Creates new process
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = info;
            proc.Start();
            //Writes commands
            using (StreamWriter writer = proc.StandardInput)
            {
                if (writer.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("ping www.google.com");
                    writer.WriteLine("exit");
                }
                writer.Close();
            }
            string PingGoogle = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            proc.Close();
        }

        //STEP 3 - Resets label and stops progress bar
        progressBarDiag.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
        progressBarDiag.Visible = false;
        lblSelectDiagnostic.Text = "Select Diagnostic to Run:";
```

-Thanks!

Comment: If you're running everything on a single thread (the UI thread) then the UI won't update until after you return. You've not shown enough code to confirm whether this is true, but the fact that you're interacting with (what look like) UI elements makes it supremely possible.

Comment: You are not going to see a progress bar animate while you are running code on the same thread that must paint the bar.  Confusion ensues when you throw in a message box, that allows paint events to be processed.  Your approach is fundamentally flawed, run expensive code in a separate worker thread so that it cannot bog down the UI thread.  BackgroundWorker is always a good choice.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the BackgroundWorker class, how would I structure step 2 to run with it?

Answer (score 1):

The progress bar will not be shown because you are painting it in the same thread where your logic is. You will have to do this in another thread. Simplest way would be to use a **backgroundworker**

This will help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I tried thread.Sleep(500), even thread.sleep(2000) and it made no difference.

Comment: That's because your sleep was causing the UI thread to sleep.  BackgroundWorker runs in a separate thread, allowing the UI thread to keep up with messages.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm not familiar with the BackgroundWorker class though, how would I write step 2 to run using it but still be able to access the PingGoogle string from the main thread ?